# Getting Too many open files error even after using try-with-resources

Tags: java, ioexception

We have an application deployed on tomcat 7 that generates csv files and moves them to archive folder after successfully uploading them to the target system.

I have written a spring-job that cleans-up files older than the threshold days value.

We are getting Too many open files error as below

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /app/CSVArchive: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:427) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:457) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.nio.file.Files.list(Files.java:3451) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at com.kg.datahub.service.impl.CleanupServiceImpl.getFiles(CleanupServiceImpl.java:50) ~[kg-datahub-framework-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.kg.datahub.job.FilesCleanupJob.execute(FilesCleanupJob.java:42) ~[kg-datahub-framework-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor414.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
```

Below is my FilesCleanupJob code ( have used try-with-resources)

```
try(final Stream<Path> olderArchiveFiles =cleanupService.getFiles(Paths.get(csvArchiveDirectory), CSV_FILE_PATTHERN, thresholdDate)){
                 LOG.info("Deleting archived files...");
                 cleanupService.deleteFiles(olderArchiveFiles); 
             }
```

Below is the cleanup service code

```
@Override
    public Stream<Path> getFiles(final Path locationPath, final String filePattern, final Date date) throws IOException {

            final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(filePattern);
            final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);

            final Function<Path, String> captureDatePart = path -> {
                    final String fileName = path.getFileName().toString();
                    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fileName);
                    return matcher.find() ? matcher.group(1) : StringUtils.EMPTY;
            };

            final Function<String, Date> convertToDate = datePart -> {
                    try {
                            return dateFormat.parse(datePart);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                            throw Throwables.propagate(e);
                    }
            };

            final Function<Date, Boolean> checkIsOlder = fileDate -> fileDate.before(date);

            final PathMatcher pathMatcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher(globPattern);

            return Files.list(locationPath).filter(Files::isRegularFile).filter(pathMatcher::matches).filter(captureDatePart.andThen(convertToDate).andThen(checkIsOlder)::apply);

    }

   @Override
    public void deleteFiles(Stream<Path> files) {
            files.map(Path::toFile).forEach(File::delete);
    }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: It is late for me, but I seem to recall we saw something similar where the error message wasn't exactly correct. The problem, IIRC, was that the number of threads we had  in the TC Application exceeded the ulimit, but it implied an open file issue. We solved the problem by increasing the process limit at the O/S level. I could be recalling incorrectly.

Comment: What are you doing with those Paths? Maybe the problem is in the deleteFiles method (or in other methods opening files and never closing them).

Comment: @JBNizet Stream<Paths> are passed to deleteFiles method where I am deleting each corresponding file. Updated the question to include deleteFiles code snippet.

Comment: As the logs show, exception occurs at the time of calling getFiles method. In local system and in lower environments I didn't face such issue.

Comment: Suppose you can open up to 1000 file descriptors. If you open 1000 in methods foo() and bar(), and forget to close them, and then call the method getFiles(), trying to open the 1001st one. That's where the exception will be thrown, but the problem is in foo() and bar(), which didn't close their files correctly. That's my point. Not saying that it *is* the problem, but that it *might be*.